# Angular TestBed (with Jasmine) outputs component to Karma test results page

Tags: angular, karma-runner

Here is the very simple Angular component:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  template: '<h1 style="background: red">Why am I here?</h1>'
})
export class SubmissionFormComponent {

}
```

And here is the test:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { SubmissionFormComponent } from './submission-form.component';

describe('SubmissionFormComponent', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SubmissionFormComponent>;

  beforeEach(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [SubmissionFormComponent]
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SubmissionFormComponent);
  });

  it('true is Truthy', () => {
    expect(true).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

And here is the output:
[Karma test results with Angular component output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8qP8.png)

The component template text "Why am I here?" is output to the test results page.

If I comment the test line:

```
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SubmissionFormComponent);
```

then "Why am I here" goes away.  Why is TestBed.createComponent outputting the component to the Karma results page?

Comment: Karma need to output the component to fetch the values

Comment: Thanks for commenting, but I'm not sure this is the case.  If I am wrong, where is it documented that karma leaves random artefacts from test subjects on its results page by design?

Comment: I am also facing this issue.

Comment: encountering this as well, would like to know the answer